# How does associativity affects the order of evaluation of operands?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

In compiler design ,If I have a grammar defined as

```
E-->E+E/E-E/id
T-->id
```

Now since this grammar is left-recursive and also we can say that both the + and - operators are left-associative so then when the parse tree would be constructed ,so if I have an input like id+id-id ,so then first id+id would be executed and then the result of addition would subtract id .

And if I have an input string like id+id+id ,then in that case execution order would be (id+id)+id .

I am not getting this concept as I have studied that Associativity of operators do not define the order of evaluation ,if that is so true then what about the parse tree generation because if we are asked to compare two parse trees and find which one would work properly if say I have an input string like id+id-id,then we would chose the parse tree wherein we have the order of evaluation such that the subtree which is rooted at node + would be executed first and then the subtree rooted at - would be executed first ,so please clarify me the actual parameters which decide the order of evaluation in the c program.

Comment: I don't think "order of evaluation of operands" means what you think it means. When you have `(a + b) + c`, the order appertains to `a`, `b` and `c`, not to the result of the expression. Of course the subexpression `a + b` is evaluated before the final expression.

Comment: Operator precedence has no impact on order of execution (except where sequence points are involved). Nor does the parse tree that the compiler generates.

Comment: Example: `int value_of_life = work_hard() + marry() + make_children()`. Depending on health and religion, the outcome can vary surprisingly depending on evaluation order of operands.

Answer (score 2):

The associativity defines whether `a - b - c` is equivalent to `(a - b) - c` or `a - (b - c)`, that is whether `c` is added to the result of adding `b` to `a` or whether the result if `b + c` is added to `a`. Associativity thus also tells you what the AST of the expression looks like.

What associativity does not tell you is which one of a, b and c is evaluated first. That is if you write `f() - g() - h()`, you know that it's equivalent to `(f() - g()) - h()` because subtraction is left-associative. However you do not know whether `f` is executed before `g` and/or `h` and so on. That's what people mean when they say that associativity does not define evaluation order.

> clarify me the actual parameters which decide the order of evaluation in the c program.

The order of evaluation of operands in an arithmetic expression in a C program is undefined. That is it is completely up to the compiler.

Comment: Okay ,I understood but then what about the parse tree which evaluates the expression in some order ,won't it evaluate the leaves first and then the upper nodes ,if it is a top-down parser ,so then if the operator is left-associative ,then won't this expression would first evaluate the leaves first and then move up.

Comment: @RADHAGOGIA The order in which the compiler (or the interpreter we were writing an interpreter instead) traverses the AST has nothing to do with the order in which the parser parses the source to generate the AST. It's still completely up to you whether you visit the left or the right subtree first (or whether you visit only one of them) in the AST traversal code - that's completely independent of the parsing algorithm used.

Comment: Sir,please explain more briefly ,I am still confused ,parser is a part of compiler itself,so then at the end evaluation is done according to AST only ,if not then what's the use of building up AST if evaluation doesn't have to take place according to AST

Comment: @RADHAGOGIA First of all a compiler does not evaluate anything (barring optimizations), it generates code, which is then evaluated by the machine. Secondly an AST is not a semantics. There's nothing about an AST that says whether the left subnode or the right subnode should be evaluated first (or at all). That is determined by the semantics of the language, which in the case of C leave it open. The use of building up the AST is that you can then walk it in whatever way you need to.